# server sent events using serverside as java rest webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Currently working on  server sent events of html5 now. I made a servlet and set the 
    `response.setContentType("text/event-stream");`
 as this. Now I get the update from this servlet on my client side and my client side code is as follows:

```
  <script >
            if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
        {

            var url = 'http://localhost:8080/KnockOut/DateFeed.jsp';
            eventSource = new EventSource(url);
            eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {
                var theParagraph = document.createElement('p');
                theParagraph.innerHTML = event.data.toString();
                document.body.appendChild(theParagraph);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
        }
    </script>
```

But when I change the url to call a rest full webservice written in java, it shows some error and I am note able to get the updated output.

The REST webservice code is:

```
 @GET
    public String getXml(@Context HttpHeaders header, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        return "dataas: " + (new java.util.Date()).toString() + "x\n\n";
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: What Error do you get ?

Comment: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at http://192.168.29.182:8080/KnockOut/resources/Items.
 

eventSource = new EventSource(url);

Comment: Do you get any other response when using `http://localhost:8080/` directly in the browser ?

Comment: yes getting..the problem is where i have to make the response headre of the webservice to "text/event-stream";I am getting error here i think.I dont know how to specify the "response.setContentType("text/event-stream");" with a rest web service.I have already experienced with @produces("text/html",application/xml,application/json)..But dont know about text/event-stream

Comment: The way setting contents header seems correct. Here is a (working ?) [example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-server-sent-events-java-servlets-example/). Maybe you can modify for a REST service. Note the UTF-8 encoding setting.

Comment: i tryed with following code for rest and is not working       atGET
    atProduces("text/html")
    public String getXml( atContext HttpHeaders header, atContext HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return "dataas: " + (new java.util.Date()).toString() + "x\n\n";
    }    at===attherate

Comment: Is `dataas:` a typo ? **Must** be `data:`.

Comment: that is only a string ..no problem with that..

Comment: The name `data:` is mandatory by [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Comment: no.actually i am returning a string it can be also like this  return "Time Now==" + (new java.util.Date()).toString() + "x\n\n"; }

Comment: You are not showing your [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5nc/index.html) annotation for the REST resource. No more clues ...

Comment: i can call my webservice in browser and i am getting correct out put.The problem is i cant call the webservice as eventSource = new EventSource(webserviceurl),and uponcalling i am getting error that i mensioned earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i got the answer

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEvent;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Irshad kk
 */

@Path("WS")
@RequestScoped

public class SSEResource {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of SSEResource
     */
    public SSEResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public String getServerSentEvents() {
        System.out.println("haii" + System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        return "data: " + "irshad" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n\n";
    }
}
```